# Reading TIFF file BitsPerSample and ImageWidth

Tags: objective-c, tiff

I'm writing an Objective-C application which can work with TIFF images in a much faster way than NSImage do (merging images with it for example costs lots of memory space), so I'm starting with a TIFF reader/writer using a combination of Objective-C and C, for best performance.

By reading [Adobe documentation for TIFF files](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf), I've been able to read every metadata of my TIFF images, with some exceptions: `BitsPerSample` and `ImageWidth`. While the other metadata returned possible values, `BitsPerSample` hexadecimal value/offset is `fffffffffffffffe` (aka. -2), while it has 3 values of size 2 (short), which means that there should be an offset in that place, and since the beginning of the TIFF file is offset 0 and the file weights 5.846.655 bytes, that offset would be invalid even if it was unsigned (18446744073709551614).

In the same way, `ImageWidth` returned value was 944, while the image width is 1200. Since I can detect that the file is a TIFF file by obtaining the short value from index 2 with length 2 and comparing it to 42, I assume my `shortIntegerFromBytesAtRangeWithEndian` function is working.

```
unsigned short shortIntegerFromBytesAtRangeWithEndian(char* bytes, unsigned long start, unsigned long length, int endian) {
    unsigned short returnedInt = 0;
    BOOL isBigEndian = endian == TIFF_IMAGE_ENDIAN_BIG;

    for (unsigned long index = isBigEndian ? 0 : length-1 ; index < length; index += endian){
        returnedInt = (returnedInt << BYTE_SIZE) + bytes[index + start];
    }

    return returnedInt;
}
```

`endian` is -1 for little endian and 1 for big endian.

Are these variables read in a different way than other values? These are the values of the image in hexadecimal and decimal, with the size in bytes (I've omitted the offset values since some of them are too big):

- **? (-2):** 0 (0) - Size: 4
- **ImageWidth (256):** 3b0 (944) - Size: 2
- **ImageLength (257):** 320 (800) - Size: 2
- **Compression (259):** 1 (1) - Size: 2
- **PhotometricInterpretation (262):** 2 (2) - Size: 2
- **StripOffsets (273):** 5a6c (23148) - Size: 4
- **Orientation (274):** 1 (1) - Size: 2
- **SamplesPerPixel (277):** 3 (3) - Size: 2
- **RowsPerStrip (278):** 320 (800) - Size: 2
- **StripByteCounts (279):** 56e400 (5694464) - Size: 4
- **PlanarConfiguration (284):** 1 (1) - Size: 2
- **ResolutionUnit (296):** 2 (2) - Size: 2
- **? (34665):** 583e6c (5783148) - Size: 4

Comment: I had to look up some really old code. My tiff reader doesn't do anything funny for imageWidth but for bitsPerSample; 
  case BitsPerSample :
   if (tagValue == 4)
    pictureType = FourBitTiff;
   if (tagValue == 0)
    tagValue = 8; // why? who knows
   bitsPerSample = tagValue;

Comment: The tag value returned in that case is -2, so I'm not sure if that's the case

Comment: What is the fType of the tag? I see a case where I shift the tag right 16 bits. But there's no comments in my code, so I don't know why.

Comment: What's a fType? Do you mean the type of the value, like int or float?

Comment: my tag struct is; tiffTag { short tagField, short fType, long length, long offset}. field type?

Comment: Ah yes, the field type is 2, which means it has type 'short' (2 bytes), however it has 3 values, which means it has the size of 6 bytes. If the size is bigger than 4 bytes, then there is an offset instead of the value, and that offset points to the real value (source: the Adobe documentation), however instead of the offset I have -2, while offset is a value equals or bigger than zero.

Comment: Here's what I have for this case; if (aTiffTag.ftype == Short && aTiffTag.length == 1)
 {
  if (IntelByteOrder && !intelCPU  || (!IntelByteOrder && intelCPU) )
   fourbyteswap((char *)&v);
  if (!intelCPU)
      shortTagValue =  v >> 16;  // drops the bottom of the data
  else
      shortTagValue = v;
  
  if (IntelByteOrder && !intelCPU  || (!IntelByteOrder && intelCPU) )
   twobyteswap((char *)&shortTagValue);
  
  tagValue = shortTagValue;
 }

Comment: I suppose IntelByteOrder is big/little endian, however what are 'v' and 'intelCPU'?

Comment: this code runs on macs and windows, so it checks the cpu type. probably can skip that now. v is the tag value.

Comment: 'length' is the length in bytes of the tag or the number of values in the tag? Because in any of these cases it still wouldn't be the case of my TIFF file, since the length is 6 bytes / 3 values :/

Comment: it seems to vary. Have you tried this tool;  http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/astifftagviewer.html

Comment: It says that my ImageWidth is 1200, and that my BitsPerSample is (16, 16, 16). I checked the binary values for ImageWidth and it seems that this app says it's 1011 0000 0000 0100 while may app says 0000 0011 1011 0000. It looks like I'm checking the wrong location by 1 byte based in that. I will check it out.

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. My app knows there are 3 short values, so it's reading the correct position I guess.

Comment: A fix: the app is saying it's 0000 0100 1011 0000. I can't see why it literally differs for 1 bit.